# Query in the topic "List"

Tags: racket, htdp

It would be a great help if someone could please tell this question:

Write a function sqr-list that consumes a list of numbers and produces a list of the squares of those numbers, computed using the built-in sqr function. Write the function by refining the template provided below.

(define (sqr-list lon)

(cond
[(empty? lon) ...]

```
[else (... (first lon) ...

       ... (sqr-list (rest lon)) ...)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read Chapter 10.

[https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3alists2%29](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_two.html#%28part._ch%7E3alists2%29)

In chapter 10 you will how to fill in the dots in the template for list producing functions. First read the entire example on `wage*` then think about how to change it to square numbers instead.